# visualization created using dc.js not rendering the y-axis data correctly

Tags: d3.js, crossfilter, dc.js

I am using `dc.js`, `crossfilter.js` to do dimensional charting. 
The chart is not correctly displaying the y-axis data i.e. showing 00000, 50000, 00000, 50000 alternatively in the y-axis. I am doing console level logging of the group and it is showing correct value.

I have segregated the problem into a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Bra2H/16)
Any clue on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: This does not appear to be a question?

Comment: posted it by mistake. currently updating it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is just clipped because it is too wide. Try setting the margins:

https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/master/web/docs/api-latest.md#marginsmargins